# Android Card Game Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, playing-cards

I have written a small card game. I now want to animate few things like taking a card from a deck and moving it to "open cards pool". I could achieve this by using translate (below code). But the problem is whenever a new card is taken and moved, the "open cards pool" looks empty. How can i possibly show the last open card in "open cards pool:? Is there a flag or something to retain the image at its original place while it is being animated?

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
```

Comment: What does "Technical Specialist" have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use two images.  When you start moving an image from the open cards pool, immediately display the next card in the same position.

If the cards look visually the same (only display the backs of the cards), then you can fake it by adding the moving card to the top of the scene and moving it while the original card never moves.